# Spree_i18n front-end custom locale

Tags: internationalization, locale, spree

I am trying to customize Spree_i18n frontend nav-bar locale and am having some issues changing it from a select_tag to a link_to. I am trying to make it appear with only two locales selections EN/CN. What would the best solution for this be?

locale.js

```
load = function() {
  return $('#locale-select select').change(function() {
    return $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: $(this).data('href'),
      data: {
        locale: $(this).val()
      }
    }).done(function() {
      return window.location.reload();
    });
  });
};
```

navbar.html.erb

```
<li id="locale-select" data-hook>
  <%= form_tag set_locale_path, class: 'navbar-form' do %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="locale" class="sr-only"><%= t(:'i18n.language') %></label>
      <%= select_tag(:locale, options_for_select(supported_locales_options, I18n.locale), class: 'form-control', data: { href: set_locale_path }) %>
      <noscript><%= submit_tag %></noscript>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

Comment: What are your issues?

Comment: I believe Spree is using sessions to change the locale. When I try   <%= link_to 'EN', set_locale_path(locale: :en), type: "Post", data: { href: set_locale_path} %>. The url will render http://localhost:3000/localeset?locale=en, and will redirect to the root_path. I would like to get rid of localeset?locale=en and have it not redirect to the root_path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My custom variant

```
<%= link_to 'en', spree.set_locale_path(switch_to_locale: :en), method: :post %>
```